# Will Windows reset 'disk' still work if copied to another drive?

Tags: windows, password-recovery

I made a password reset 'disk' on a USB thumb drive (wanted to use a CD for better convenience and reliability but it appears this is no longer permitted - pretty sure it was an option in Windows 7 - even though *the use of a floppy disk is still supported* ... go figure). This use of a pre-cooked reset disk seemed to be the only way (and I have done a lot of Googling on this) for the user of a local account to change their password (whether because it is forgotten or simply because they elect to make the change) on a Windows 10 (and earlier perhaps) system without losing various user data associated with the existing credentials, as would happen if, for example, an administrator reset the particular user's password.

Anyway ... the reset 'disk' appears to be just a couple of files in the root of the thumb drive volume, one called "userkey.psw" and the other ".device_info_e7f7f2a9-2 ... *[long alphanumeric string]* ". I plan to copy these files elsewhere as a backup in case the thumb drive is lost/fails/etc, since if the user were to forget their password then a reset disk cannot simply be created anew as doing so requires the particular user to be logged on to the system. Note that the ".device_info_ ..." file is not a regular file: it is 0 KB and has no creation nor modification date; it might be just an entry in the file table for the purpose of recording the information that is present in its name.

So, my question: can a duplicate thumb drive be created at some later date by simply copying the two files above described into the root directory of a different device? Or are these files somehow locked to the original hardware? Or maybe there is a workaround, like cloning the volume from the original drive to the new drive with e.g. Macrium Reflect.

I appreciate that I could grab a spare thumb drive and experiment but this would not be a substitute for a full understanding of what is going on 'under the hood' - I prefer to know not just that something works, but *why* it works.

Just to be clear, this is a *local account*, it is not associated in any way with a Microsoft Account.

Comment: The bootable environment you have created generic

Comment: @Ramhound I don't at all understand your comment; did you post it here unintentionally?